# PHP Replace Constant reference with value from variable

Tags: php

I'm using an API that controls the sort order of records as part of a find request - the syntax for the method is:

```
$request->addSortRule('Articles::Year', 1, FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND)
$request->addSortRule('Articles::Year', 1, FILEMAKER_SORT_DESCEND)
```

It uses a constant of either `FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND` or `FILEMAKER_SORT_DESCEND` to specify the sort order, and `'Articles::Year'` is the field name to sort on.

Rather than hard code the field name and sort order I would like to make this dynamic, e.g. something like this:

```
$sortField = 'Articles::Year';
$sortOrder = 'FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND';

$request->addSortRule(''.$sortField.'', 1, $sortOrder);
```

This isn't working for me - no error but the find request fails. If I use the following version with the dynamic reference to the field name it does work:

```
$request->addSortRule(''.$sortField.'', 1, FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND)
```

but I'm still hardcoding the sort order constant. Is it possible to make the reference to the constant dynamic here so I can have one sort line instead of 2 (to handle ascending or descending)?

Comment: `'FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND'` is a string, have you tried without the quotes?

Comment: fyi, `''.$sortField.''` could just be `$sortField`

Comment: `$request->addSortRule(''.$sortField.'', 1, constant($sortOrder));`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments this is working for me now:

```
$sortField = 'Articles::Year';
$sortOrder = FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND;

$request->addSortRule(''.$sortField.'', 1, $sortOrder);
```